# How can I send an SMS for free with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sms

I am trying to find a free API that allows me to send an SMS for free. I have not started programming the software yet, in case you needed to know

I have been searching online, but I can only find ones that cost money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past using email however you do need to know the carrier of the recipient. It's not the prettiest but it gets the job done.

for example 1234567890@txt.att.net would send a text to that number if they are an AT&T customer.
example code:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
sender = 'someemail@gmail.com'
passwd = '123456'
server.login(sender, passwd)


server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
```